# Can I change face selection transparency?

Tags: customization, selection-tools

I want to reduce face selection alfa, because, for example when I setting up UV often I just can't see the result, until I deselect. I tried to search how to change it in preferences, but didn't find anything helpful. Google also didn't help

Can it be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Themes > User Interface > UV Image Editor > Face Selected, click it to bring up the color controls panel, lower the Alpha (bottom control) to what works for you.

The same can be done in Edit > Preferences > Themes > User Interface > 3D Viewport > Face Selected.  If you want your new settings next time you open Blender then click the Save Preferences button in the lower left of the Blender Preferences window.

[image]

Comment: In 2.93.4 it is just `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Themes` > `UV Image Editor` \ `3D Viewport`. Not in `User interface` section. However, thank You

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were asking for 2.93, my answer's for the current 3.0.